# is it possible to add extra field in req.body and add them in a collection using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store some values in a collection like i got a req.body at the endpoint and i wanted to add timestamp inside the req.body object.
like here is the req.body object

```
{
name:'xanderous',
city:'Delhi'}
```

and i want to convert this into this way

```
{
name:'xanderous',
city:'Delhi',
timestamp:1235456555}
```

how can i try to solve this issue

```
const profileStore = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    // console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))

    await db.collection('Profiles').doc(`${req.body.phoneNumber}`).set(req.body,{merge:true})
    console.log('profile')
    res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: `Success` })

  } catch (error) { 
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};

module.exports = {profileStore};
```

i know i can add the timestamp as an extra field outside the req.body but i have stored the value in the req.body format so i need to store in the given scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
const newBody = {
  timestamp: Date.now(),
  ...req.body
}  
await db.collection('Profiles').doc(`${req.body.phoneNumber}`).set(newBody,{merge:true})
```

Comment: are you sure this is the right answer? because when i am deploying this i am getting an error 
error Parsing error: Unexpected token ..

Comment: either you missed one of the dots, or you are running an old Node.js version that doesn't support this feature yet. If your version of node is old, you can accomplish the same thing with `Object.assign()`